# Find out if a relationships between two variables is stronger in specific clusters defined by other variables

Tags: regression, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I am a bit rusted so I hope you will be able to help me out on this:

I am working with a big dataset of 100+ features. I am interested in the nature of the relationship between two variables specifically, a dummy dependent one and a continuous independent one. Just taking into account these two the relationship is very weak and not significant, however I'd like to find out if in specific areas of the 100+ features space it becomes stronger. In other words if smaller clusters of my dataset defined by some of these 100+ features present a stronger correlation between the specific two variables I am looking at.

What kind of strategy I can use to run such analysis?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Sorry for being unclear, I can try with an example:

I have the following variables:

1. survived (dependent)
2. weight (independent)
3. age
4. country

Now I am interested in the relationship between 2 and 1: it is pretty weak overall, but I want to find out if it's stronger in specific portion of the data defined with 3 or/and 4- for example in the clusters age < 40 or country = USA or both together.

In my real example I have hundreds of additional features to explore and I am trying to find the best way.

I am thankful for the data viz tip, it's what I have been focusing so far but I am thinking if I can scale it up.

Comment: Producing some simple interaction-style plots of the two chosen features by various 3rd features (as an interaction) could provide some valuable insights. I can't count how many times basic plots like these have given me direction in my analysis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.